# Dll export friend operator>>

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I'm creating this class:

```
///> MyObject.h file
class __declspec(dllexport) CMyObject
{
public:
    int m_Intero;
public:
    CMyObject();
    ~CMyObject();
public:
    friend std::wifstream& operator>>(std::wifstream& is, CMyObject& eprt);
}
///> MyObject.cpp
std::wifstream& operator>>(std::wifstream& is, CMyObject& myobj)
{
    if (is.is_open())
        ///> Input operations.

    return is;
}
```

When I compile the library I get no errors, but when I use my library in the final project I get this error:

```
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol reference "class std::basic_ifstream<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t> > & __cdecl operator>>(...) in function "public: void __thiscall ...
```

I guess I have to specify somehow that my operator>> function have to be exported.

How should I modify my code?

Answer (score 3):

Few aspects:

- You are exporting the class, not the global (friend) function. You're just letting the compiler know that global function (operator overload) is a friend. You need to **export** the function.
- When C++ objects are concerned, you better not export such functions, because compiler differences will make classes to have different sizes.

Comment: Well from point two I should assume that I do not have to export operator >> friend and then I can't use it to load data from file. Is that correct?

Comment: EDIT: I've done a "LoadFromFile" function and used operator >> inside here. Is correct?

Comment: friend __declspec(dllexport) std::wifstream& operator>>(std::wifstream& is, CMyObject& eprt);

should solve your prolem.

Comment: @munsingh, yes, but what's the guarantee that `CMyObject` is same for the DLL and for the DLL client (mostly the EXE)?  What if DLL changes, and it also changes the size (or vptr table) ?  If the DLL and client(s) are not part of same build suite, exporting classes isn't right.